# SpringBoot project, Environment Variable in application.yml always empty

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to run a SpringBoot project that runs with docker-compose. i started its dependencies (Redis, MongoDB ,and RabbitMQ) with `docker-compose up`

and i'm building the project and running it with these commands
`mvn clean package -DskipTests && mvn spring-boot:run`

I keep having these errors :

`Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOp  erationsConfiguration$RequestScopedConfiguration`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'OAUTH_CLIENTID' in value "${OAUTH_CLIENTID}"`

In the docker-compose file, the values of the environment variables are defined in the environment section.

```
 environment:
      - RABBIT_HOST=rabbitstomp
      - RABBIT_USER=guest
      - RABBIT_PASS=user
      - MONGO_HOST=mongodb://localhost:27017
      - OAUTH_CLIENTID=nz-kek
      - OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=DzXZxeOZOJHFZIUhObSpsne
      - SSO_HOST=https://webweb.com
      - CORS_HOSTS=HOST1,HOST2
      - SES_HOST=ses
      - SES_PORT=6000
      - REDIS_HOST=localhost
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
```

This is how application.yml looks like :

```
     spring.data.mongodb:
  database: ${DB_NAME} #notificationdb
  uri: ${MONGO_HOST}
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwk:
        key-set-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/keys
      token-info-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/userinfo
    client:
      client-id: ${OAUTH_CLIENTID}
          client-secret: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}`
```

So when running the project without docker-compose, am i supposed to put the values in the application.yml ?

i also tried `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--path.to.value=value1`, but i'm not sure how the path should be with variables like `key-set-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/keys`

Comment: You are running docker, but starting Spring Boot locally... How should that see the docker environment variables?

Comment: The application is supposed to be started with `docker-compose`, and the environment variables are defined in the docker-compose file as mentioned in my original post. What I'm asking is there's away to pass these parameters like `key-set-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/keys 
` ,when starting the application as a spring boot app (with `mvn spring-boot:run` or `java -jar`).

Comment: They are available BUT it is to be run inside a docker container (and you shouldn't be using `mvn spring-boot:run` insde a container to start the application). From what I see here, you are only starting your external dependencies with docker and run your app locally.

Comment: When i use `mvn spring-boot:run`, it's not inside the container. i'm running it locally on my computer. I build the project using Intellij or the Terminal.

Comment: Hence it will not work as those environment variables aren't there. Those are only available inside docker.  The name of the variable is `sso-host` or `SSO_HOST` just as you declare them (there is some leniency in Spring BOot hence both should work).

Comment: @M.Deinum So it must always be started inside a Container ? no way to start it as a  jar or with the IDE in dev mode ?

Comment: Sure you can but you have to specify ALL the environment variables you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has support for providing default values in the configuration via the [PlaceholderConfigurerSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html). The default value is what comes after the `:`. In your case, you should write:

```
client-id: ${OAUTH_CLIENTID:yourDevelopmentDefaultClientID}
```

If you use the `@Value` annotation to inject the values, you have support to SpEL for using expressions of the type: `#{someExpression}` for more complex cases.

**UPDATE:**

In your case, I believe you are reversing the position of the variables. The correct should be:

```
key-set-uri: ${SSO_HOST:auth-server}/keys
```

Here is what it means: first, it will try to use the `SSO_HOST` environment variable, which is provided to the container through docker-compose. In case this variable is not provided to the process, Spring will use `auth-server` as the address of the server. It seems to me that this address is visible only inside the docker-compose network, so if you are running your app outside this network, the `auth-server` address will not be visible. Do you know where is the auth server? Is it another docker container? Is it running on localhost?

Some interesting reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults

Comment: But how to specify the values of `auth-server` and `SSO_HOST` in in `key-set-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/keys` ?. In docker-compose file their values are specified, but i don't seem to find any definition of their values in the project.
is running these arguments with `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=` is an option ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the position of the variables, but the order `key-set-uri: ${auth-server:${SSO_HOST}}/keys` is defined in a version of the project that's supposed to work. And about the auth server. I think it's deployed somewhere on the cloud. In case I have the URL, Should i hardcode the value in application.yml ?

Comment: In my opinion, to run the application outside docker, you should hardcode the address of the server as a fallback for the SSO_HOST environment variable, providing: `key-set-uri: ${SSO_HOST:<your remote address here>}`. This way, if the env variable is not present, Spring will use the address you provided. However, be careful to not expose credentials on your source code repository. Another option (safer) is to provided the SSO_HOST variable in your .bash_rc or .profile files. Spring will load them when starting the app.

Comment: That's actually what i did. I put the values of the environment variables in `~/.profile`, so now they are loaded when i start the app with Intellij or when running `mvn spring-boot:run` on the terminal.

Comment: Good and safe solution! But, in this case, you had to change the position, right?

Comment: No I didn't. and i didn't specify any value for `auth-server` because when i looked in the `docker-compose` file and the Kubernetes configuration (for testing environment), i didn't find any possible value. 
so now i'm running the project without it and everything seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pass env variables in docker compose as object not a list:

```
environment:
  RABBIT_HOST: rabbitstomp
  RABBIT_USER: guest
  RABBIT_PASS: user
  MONGO_HOST: mongodb://localhost:27017
  OAUTH_CLIENTID: nz-kek
  OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET: DzXZxeOZOJHFZIUhObSpsne
  SSO_HOST: https://webweb.com
  CORS_HOSTS: HOST1,HOST2
  SES_HOST: ses
  SES_PORT: 6000
  REDIS_HOST: localhost
  REDIS_PORT: 6379`
```